# Pop-up calendar widget of QDateEdit on mouseclick anywhere in text area and not just the down arrow,

Tags: qt, eventfilter, qcalendarwidget

I used event filter on my QDateEdit 'sdateEdit' as follows:

```
bool Class::eventFilter ( QObject *obj, QEvent *event )
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {      
        sdateEdit->calendarWidget()->show();

    }
    else
        return QObject::eventFilter ( obj, event );
}
```

But this doesnt work.
I tried .. sdateEdit->setCalendarPopup(true). This did not work as well.

Comment: Explain yourself better, where do you click, what do you want to happen after clicking, currently your question is not clear

Comment: in qdateedit , when we click on down arrow then its calendar widget pops up. But i need calendar to pop up when we click anywhere inside qdateedit box.

Comment: okay, what is `Class`?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: its just a class name i have given here. My concern here is to pop up the calendar widget of qdateedit on my mouseclick. Is there any signal to pop the calendar widget?

Comment: Yes! I used this idea and created my own calendar widget which shows itself whenerver QDateEdit::lineedit() is mousepressed. 
And I used signal SelectionChanged() of QCalendarWidget to edit lineedit() of QDateEdit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I have implemented a custom QDateEdit, the strategy is to use eventFilter when you click on the QLineEdit and send a click event to the arrow:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class DateEdit: public QDateEdit
{
public:
    DateEdit(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QDateEdit(parent)
    {
       lineEdit()->installEventFilter(this);
    }
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override
    {
        if(watched == lineEdit() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
            QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
            opt.init(this);
            QRect r = style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_ComboBoxArrow, this);
            QPoint p = r.center();
            QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, p, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            QCoreApplication::sendEvent(this, event);
        }
        return QDateEdit::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DateEdit w;
    w.setCalendarPopup(true);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```